# Release not working on different PC

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, release

I am not so experienced with C++ and MS Visual Studio. I am currently having issue with releasing .exe and trying to run the program on different PC. In the program I'm using additional library (magick++). I've configured the **Runtime Library** in Visual Studio 2015 to **Multi-threaded (/MT)**. I suppose, that with this configuration the .exe file should be running on different PCs, but when I try to run it, message with "*CORE_RL_Magick++. dll is missing on this computer* appears. Any idea, what might be wrong?

My second question is, if I would like to make a release with dynamic library **/MD**, how can I get the library to run it on different PC? Or do I have to install the library first (I mean if I have to install Imagemagick to the computer or is there some way I can get the nescessary library from the build in Visual Studio).

Thanks for every information.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have CORE_RL_Magick++. dll in the path (including the directory that your exe program is running) somewhere on the computer that is failing.

The /MD and /MT commands effect what runtime is used, not what other libraries the program is dependant on.

So with /MT, it will compile a static version of the visual c libs into the exe, but if linked against the magic dll, it will still need that CORE_RL_Magick++. dll in order to run.

Comment: This might be stupid question, but the dll shoud be in some specific path, or as I assume I cane have it in the same folder as the exe file?

Comment: same directory, or one that is in the path such as windows\system32 etc

Answer (score 1):

I think **/MD** is a better choice, for smaller size.

If you want to run program on other PC, you may need to install `Visual Studio Redistributable` (could be downloaded on Microsoft website) on the PC first.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Martin Zhai. I had this problem when attempting to run my program on another machine after upgrading to 2015. The DLL I wanted to use would not be found despite being local. Installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) fixed this.

Comment: I've installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for VS 2015 (x86 same as the program), but I still get the error, that the library "CORE_RL_Magick++. dll" is missing, but it is in the same folder as the .exe file.

Comment: Check which other redistributables are installed on your dev machine and ensure these are installed on you target machine. It may be a case that the .dll you are using (since you didn't build it) requires an earlier redistributable or a redistributable package not installed on target machine. You can always use a Dependency walker on your .exe, or check the Event log which may give more indications about while the dll failed to load. (maybe wrong version of .dll or something).